# The query 'name contains <filename>' does not work as prefix match when the argument is too long

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to confirm the action of the query term 'name contains ...' appears in file.list() api, which seems to work differently depending on the length of the argument.

I prepared a file with long name ('0123456789012345678901234567890123456789' == '0123456789'*4) on the google drive and tried to find it using 'name contains ...' query term with file.list API.

The tests on https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list returned as following,

```
name contains '0123456789' -> OK
name contains '01234567890123456789' -> OK
name contains '01234567890123456789012345' -> OK
name contains '012345678901234567890123456' -> NG
name contains '012345678901234567890123456789' -> NG
name contains '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789' -> OK
```

From above results, it seems that,

- When the length of the argument is 26 or less, the 'name contains' query works as the 'prefix match' as documented in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#file_properties.
- When the length is more than 26, the 'name contains' query works as the 'exact match' in similar to 'name = '.

I would appreciate it if this action is correct and is documented somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, this does not work as intended or documented. I've take the liberty to open an issue tracker report for this, you can consult the case on the following link to follow the updates:

https://issuetracker.google.com/144979954

Comment: Thank you for your comment and bug-reporting. I would like to follow it, too.